# What is the best approach of building SAP Hybris application from scratch?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to build my first app on Hybris, but I'm not sure what is the best approach to build such applications. Let's say I sell flowers in my store. Currently there are 2 ways how to do it:

1. Create accelerator template and then reconfigure application.
2. Building app from the beginning.

The first solution may look very attractive, but I don't think it is better solution because:

1. Hybris doesn't provide an accelerator for my specific solution (flowers), application reconfiguration may take a lot of time.
2. Some accelerators contain more that one store - other stores should be removed.
3. The mess in the database. I have to spend time and understand which tables should be removed.

The second approach seems the most logical, but in this case I have some doubts, because the speed of development will be significantly reduced. Moreover, I think that developing a simple store on Spring Boot will be much faster than learning the Hybris platform's extensions and how they work together.

In this case, how should I start develop my application?

Comment: If you are beginner in Hybirs, i strongly recommend using the existing templates. Deleting tables from the Database may lead to a lot of problems, which take too much time to fix. Don't do that, unless you are pretty sure what you are doing. If you want to have minimal store, just remove the unwanted extensions. And finally think if you really need Hybris for that. There are a lot of other shop solutions, which may fit you requirements.

Comment: Thank you @Hristo. Yes, I'm beginner. Unfortunately (or fortunately :)) I have to work with this platform and I can't choose another one. I mention Spring Boot just as example. You said that using existing templates it is the best solution - could you please clarify why? How such applications usually created?

Comment: The main idea is because you already have everything up and running. With a ready to deploy  system is much more easier to learn and understand how the things are done and what are the processes behind it. In Hybris 6 gradle installer, there are recipes, which should cover your needs. If you want to start from scratch, another solution would be, to take one recipe/template as an example, and try building you store like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I don't have experience with building complete SAP Hybris application from the scratch yet, but I have some experience related to development of the SAP Hybris extensions, so I'll try to provide my potential approach because I don't see many answers here.

I'd do it as follows:

1. Get the whole commerce suite
2. Run one of the recipe with the installer script (choose one, which will be the best for you - one of the most popular/common recipes is `b2c_acc`)
3. Remove unwanted extensions from the `localextensions.xml` file if necessary
4. Add another extensions, if you need them
5. Depending on your use case, create your own extension basing on the one of templates with `ant extgen` task inside the `hybris/bin/platform/` dir (e.g. `yacceleratorstorefront`, `ybackoffice`, `yempty`, etc.)
6. Add your custom extension (or extensions) to `localextensions.xml` file
7. Start your development within your custom extension created out of available template

I know, it's kind of "specific" platform. I hope this answer will help a bit.

Cheers